# Removing null values from a Guava SetMultimap?

Tags: java, guava

If I have a SetMultimap like the following:

```
SetMultimap<String, MyObject> map = HashMultimap.create();
map.put("a", new MyObject());
map.put("a", null);
map.put("b", null);
```

What is the best way to remove the null values from this collection, so that I end up with something like (i.e. some keys will have only null values, but I still want the key):

```
   a -> obj
   b -> empty
```

Comment: If you can iterate over it, just remove the nulls in a loop.

Comment: What do you suppose should represent *empty*?

Comment: Note that in a Multimap, there's no such thing as a key "present" but not mapped to any values.  A key is either mapped to one or more values, or it's totally absent from the `Multimap`.

Comment: thanks Lewis, makes sense. I just ended up doing: Collection<MyObject> myObjects = map.get(key); myObjects.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Multimap<String, String> filteredMap = Multimaps.filterValues(map, Predicates.notNull());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a filter view on for values and clear it:

```
Multimaps.filterValues(map, Predicates.isNull()).clear();
```

This will remove `null` values from the original map.

**Sample**

```
HashMultimap<String, Object> map = HashMultimap.create();

map.put("a", "x");
map.put("a", null);
map.put("b", null);

System.out.println("before: " + map);

Multimaps.filterValues(map, Predicates.isNull()).clear();

System.out.println("after: " + map);
```

Prints:

```
before: {b=[null], a=[null, x]}
after: {a=[x]}
```